# Prove that multiplication is a well-defined operation on the quotient group $R/\mathcal{J}$ where $\mathcal{J}$ is an ideal and $R$ a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, quotient-group

**Problem Statement**

Suppose $R$ is a ring and $\mathcal{J} \subset R$ is a (two-sided) ideal. The quotient additive group $R/\mathcal{J}$ is the set of cosets, which in the additive notation, have the form $r + \mathcal{J}$ for $r \in R$

Prove that: $$(r + \mathcal{J})(s + \mathcal{J}) = rs + \mathcal{J}$$ Well defines an operation on $R/\mathcal{J}$

---

**My attempt**

So for this problem we want to show that if $r + \mathcal{J} = r' + \mathcal{J}$ and $s + \mathcal{J} = s' + \mathcal{J}$ then that means that $rs + \mathcal{J} = r's' + \mathcal{J}$

To that end I noted that for any $a \in R$ the equation $a + \mathcal{J} = a' + \mathcal{J}$ implies that:

1. $a,a'$ belong to the same left coset of $\mathcal{J}$ and
2. $(-a) + a' = a' - a \in \mathcal{J}$

Since this applies to both $r$ and $s$ we can utilize these facts and note that both $$(r' - r),\ (s' -s) \in \mathcal{J}$$ Since $\mathcal{J}$ is a (two-sided) ideal we can say that $$(r'-r)(s'-s) = r's' - r's - s'r + rs \in \mathcal{J}$$
Now I was hoping that by utilizing these facts and through expanding we would end up with something like $r's' - rs$ which we can clearly see is an element of $\mathcal{J}$ which would be equivalent to the statement that $rs + \mathcal{J} = r's' + \mathcal{J}$. However, of course that's not what we end up with.

---

So, I'm wondering am I on the right track but just potentially missing some small property or having some oversight? Or is my approach totally wrong and I need to rethink this problem from a different angle? I appreciate any guidance here.

Comment: What about $(r'-r)s'+r(s'-s)$ instead of $(r'-r)(s'-s)$?

Comment: Hint: try to do it in two steps: show that $rs-rs'$ lies in $\mathcal{J}$, then show that $rs'-r's'$ lies in $\mathcal{J}$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Michael and Arturo. I was able to show that since $\mathcal{J}$ is an ideal that the products above are elements of $\mathcal{J}$ and since an ideal is a subgroup that their sum is also an element of $\mathcal{J}$ and then the middle terms cancel out and we get what we were looking for.